# Azure AD SAML2 SSO wrong NameID format

Tags: single-sign-on, saas, entra-id

I am trying to integrate a SaaS application with an autonomous (not federated with anything) Azure Active Directory for SSO purposes. The SaaS application (the Service Provider) is SAML2 compliant (SP-initiated), so this should work. However, inside the SAMLRequest, the SP specifies

`<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />`

And when AAD answers, the NameID is formatted with `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent`.

It is weird: the documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195589.aspx), paragraph "NameIDPolicy Element in AuthnRequest" lists 'unspecified' as a possible request format...

As the SaaS application expects 'unspecified' instead of 'persistent', it fails.

Would anyone know of a method to get 'unspecified' format instead with Azure AD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx) they have a warning:

> Azure AD currently supports the following NameID Format URI for SAML 2.0:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent.

This is vague but I assume it means that is ALL that they support.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, even if not a definitive answer. We were eventually able to change this at the SP level.

Answer (score 0):

We just did some investigations and learned that if you do some string manipulation on the NameID then AAD changes the format to 'unspecified'.